# Print objects in Array on different rows in spreadsheet using AdWords Scripts / Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, printing, rows, google-ads-api

As the title describes, I have some problems understanding how I should print objects in my Array on different rows on a spreadsheet using Google AdWords.

```
 var SPREADSHEET_URL = "xxxx";

function main(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

 var headrows = [
  ['Kund',
  'Spend',
  'Budget',
  'Average',
  'Prognos',
  'Status']];
var range = sheet.getRange('A1:F1');
 range.setValues(headrows);

 Logger.log(getCalc().accountArr.name);  
}

function getCalc(){
  var monthObj = {};
  var sevenObj = {};
  var nameObj = {};
  var progObj = {};
  var accountArr = [];
  var dagarPrognos = getDagar().daysLeft;

   var accountIterator = MccApp.accounts()
   .withIds(['xx', 'xx','xx'])
   .get();

   while(accountIterator.hasNext()){
    var account = accountIterator.next()
    nameObj = account.getName();
    var statsMonth = account.getStatsFor("THIS_MONTH");
    var statsSeven = account.getStatsFor("LAST_7_DAYS");
    monthObj = statsMonth.getCost();
    var seven = statsSeven.getCost();
    sevenObj = seven / 7;

    progObj = ((seven * dagarPrognos) + monthObj);

accountArr.push({"name": nameObj, "month": monthObj, "seven": sevenObj, "prognos": progObj});  
}

  return{account: accountArr};
}
```

My goal is to print out objects in the array "accountArray" or as I returned it "account".

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is given in this example: https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/solutions/ad-performance

Check out the write value to row section:

```
// Write data to our rows.
for (var key in segmentMap) {
  ...
  rows.push(row);
}
```